# 302 Found status in SoapUI

Tags: redirect, post, soapui, http-status-code-302

Redirect should happen after `POST` request, but response in `SoapUI` shows just an error message:

> This document has moved

I am looking for some JMeter-like "Follow redirects" option in `SoapUI`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [this documentation](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/reference/overview.html)?

In Request Property (Click on the Properties tab at the bottom of the panel to view the properties)

> Follow Redirects - follows HTTP Redirect response messages.

Is Follow Redirects property set to true?

Comment: Yes, but it stay on the same page.

Comment: Are you using Basic Auth?

Comment: No, it is without authentication.

Comment: Okay, nevermind then. Have you tried an other testing tool to make sure the problem comes from SoapUI?

Comment: Yes, I used it in `JMeter`. Is it possible to set maximal number of redirects?

Comment: _I believe this is done by setting a property to control the redirect limit, -Dsoapui.redirect.limit=20_ [from this post](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Increase-redirect-limit/td-p/120597)

Comment: In which variable should I set this flag in `soapui.bat` file? In `set JAVA_OPTS` maybe?

Comment: [There are several ways to set properties](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/working-with-properties.html#2-Setting-properties-from-the-command-line) but that flag _can be set directly from the command-line when running any of the SoapUI bat/sh files_

Comment: I see, but I start it with a shortcut.

Comment: Then I would suggest trying the _Property Editors_ (first section of the article I linked in my last comment) there are three ways you can set it, e.g. _From the selected objects main editor window in a Properties inspector_